# Static Objects in Python

Tags: python, object, static

I have a complex set of classes that i call through a rest API. When I make calls through the rest interface, the class objects are created an they are persisted or they die at the end of the call. I want these objects to stay in memory so I dont have to create and kill the object every time I make the call. Any suggestions of how I can do this. A friend suggested using something like a static class , but I dont seem to find how I can achieve this is python

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about how your server is implemented I suggest that you could use some kind of cache, e.g. [memcached](http://www.memcached.org/). You can use [python-memcached](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-memcached) to interface to it, or a framework specific one such as those for django, bottle, flask et. al.